# Django: queryset using __gte shows wrong results after serialization

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm facing an extremely weird issue while showing filtered results.

Here's my api method:

```
...
    @list_route(methods=['GET'], url_path='internal-users')
    def internal(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = models.User.objects.internal_users()

        data = self.get_serializer(users, many=True, context={'request': request}).data

        return response.Ok(data)
...
```

Here's the `internal_users()` call of User model:

```
...
    def internal_users(self) -> Union[QuerySet, List['User']]:
        queryset = super(UserManager, self).get_queryset()

        queryset = queryset.filter(role_policy__gte=constants.UserRolePolicy.editor) # role_polict >= 63

        return queryset
...
```

Up until this point, the control `->` shows the correct query formation and results.

```
...
    @list_route(methods=['GET'], url_path='internal-users')
    def internal(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = models.User.objects.internal_users()
        # -> correct results
        data = self.get_serializer(users, many=True, context={'request': request}).data

        return response.Ok(data)
...
```

[image]

However, as soon as I pass my objects to serializer in the next line, the results automatically reduce to only those users with role_policy EQUAL TO 63.

Here's the serializer:

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'uuid',
            'email',
            'given',
            ...
            'phone',
        ]
```

What could be the issue? Please help.

Comment: what does `response.Ok` ?

Comment: It returns only 5 users instead of ~30 users. Those 5 users are the ones where role_policy is EQUAL to 63. All those results where user's role policy is Greater Than 63 are ignored for some reason.

Comment: what I meant is, what operation does `response.Ok` ? this isn't a Django REST framework method. Might be it is the culprit

Comment: @Linovia oh that's a generic wrapper response that I've created to indicate a 200 status. It's used across the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The `role policy` is a text field rather than an integer field. That's why `__gte` didn't work.

It's quite misleading from Django though as the query was formed perfectly.